# Python can't find analyze() script

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-analysis

In the book "Python Artificial Intelligence Projects for Beginners" by Joshua Eckroth, in the project about Youtube Spam, seems like it can't find the analyze() Does anyone know what has changed since the book was published in 2018?

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>d=pd.read_csv("Youtube01-Psy.csv")
>>>d
>>>d.tail()
>>>len(d.query("CLASS==1"))
>>>len(d.query("CLASS==0"))
>>>len(d)
>>>from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>>vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
>>>dvec = vectorizer.fit_transform(d["CONTENT"])
>>>dvec
>>>print(d["CONTENT"][349])
>>>analyze(d["CONTENT"][349])
```

Comment: Please show us your code, and the error.

Comment: we don't know book `"Python Artificial Intelligence Projects for Beginners` and we don't know `project about Youtube Spam`. You should add link to this book and project - if it exists on internet.

Comment: if you want to use `analyze()` then first you have to `import` this function from some module. But we don't know what module it should be. We don't know this project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `analyze()` then first you have to

- `import` this function from some module
- or write this function in your code

---

Using `Google` I searched `Python Artificial Intelligence Projects for Beginners`

and on GitHub I found [Python Artificial Intelligence Projects for Beginners](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Python-Artificial-Intelligence-Projects-for-Beginners)
and source code for [Spam detector.py](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Python-Artificial-Intelligence-Projects-for-Beginners/blob/master/Chapter03/Spam%20detector.py)

and there is line which you don't have

```
analyze = vectorizer.build_analyzer()
```

and this should resolve your problem.